# php query not returning rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this MySql query that is not returning the output but If I define a limit below 200 records the return works ( return the records ).

normally this query must return 5000 records .

So the question is what I doing wrong and what I have to Do to return all rows .

Is there any configuration in php.ini or other file that fix this query?

```
    getConnection();
    $connection =  getConnection();
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM estadoactual limit 200");
    $stmt->execute( );

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode($rows);
```

If I put limit 200 the query works but if I remove this limit then don't

I try exand de the memory limit in php.ini to 512MB/2048MB but not work

Comment: In what way doesn't it work above 200 records? btw the mysql_* extension was removed from PHP version 7 you should now be using PDO

Comment: You'll need to tell us what goes wrong. Just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't give people much to go on!

Comment: Maybe you are hitting the memory limit or execution time limit in PHP? Too many things, you need to debug more. Is error logging enabled and being checked?

Comment: Run query without limitation & share logs please.

Comment: Do not use `mysql_query` as it is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)  from PHP 5.5

Comment: This is probably a character encoding problem. Use `mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8")` before doing the query. Having said that: please convert your code to `mysqli` or `PDO`, as these `mysql_` functions are not supported anymore in the latest versions of PHP.

Comment: my server hostmonster uses Php 5.5 ,   I never work with PDO  how I change that query to work with PDO ?

Comment: Here is the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) manual

Comment: I change the code but with pdo not return all rows @MaxZoom

Comment: @trincot this is the right answer to my problem. please post it so I can mark this one correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_encode` will fail with the value `false` when the string passed to it has invalid UTF8 sequences. This practically means one of your records has a string with non-ASCII characters, and a different character encoding is used. There are other possible reasons as well, but often this is the problem.

When `json_encode` returns `false`, you should [check which error occurred with `json_last_error_msg`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script/35391449#35391449).

When reading data from the database, make sure to use `utf-8` encoding. In your case you should use call this function:

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8")
```

...before doing the query.

Having said that: please convert your code to `mysqli` or `PDO`, as these `mysql_`  functions were deprecated a few years ago, and are not supported anymore in the latest versions of PHP.